# Bind the ‘<‘ and ‘>’ char in the tkinter text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have got a tkinter text widget, and I want to bind the ‘<‘ and ‘>’ char. But when I try to use the following code:

```
text.bind('<', func)
```

This is what I got:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no event type or button # or keysym
```

So how can bind these keypresses to the text widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<less>` for character `<` and `<greater>` for character `>`.